# Remove Background of image in Button which has Image and text in Android

Tags: android, image, button, background

i have a big buttons with images and text.i want to remove white background behind image.

**Xml code:**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:shadowColor="#f9f9f9"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/message"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:text="Message"
        android:textColor="#52595C"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
```

i am trying this to remove background but it not working

> android:background="@null"

Any Help  will be much Apeaciated!

Comment: i want that the Message image which i set on button Should have no background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to button to be transparent, use this:

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

If you want to image to have a transparent background, you have to use a transparent png file, like this: http://content.mediastg.net/dyna_images/agents/225/137213/20140920014206.png

If you want to learn how to make transparent images:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r17b_QK_9Ng

Comment: Make sure you do not have two "android:background". Only one of them should be in your snippet

Comment: ok.using this line makes my button transparent, i want to remove background of image and my button Should have gray color.

Comment: Ok buddy! That is not a programming problem - but a image problem! Are you sure you are using a transparent png? for example, try this: http://content.mediastg.net/dyna_images/agents/225/137213/20140920014206.png

Comment: ohh.. you are right! em using png images but they are not transparent. Thanks buddy

Comment: Can you tell me from where i can find transparent icons images that i can use

Comment: Or if you want to learn a bit, watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r17b_QK_9Ng

Comment: thank you soo much. :) you can edit your Answer i will Accept

Comment: I included all options in the asnwer

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:src="@drawable/button_style"
    android:shadowColor="#f9f9f9"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/message"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:text="Message"
    android:textColor="#52595C"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
```

This maybe work,set `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` To avoid use background twice, you can use ImageButton to replace Button and use android:src to set the picture as background

Comment: it makes my buttons background transparent. i want my button in gray color, i want to remove background of the image only.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not possible by setting background. The only way is  change to another image